# How do I inject a CSS stylesheet call during XSLT transformation from XML > XML

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I am working on an XSLT transform from one XML doc to another XML doc because I need to present some of the content in a different order and I want to inject the CSS stylesheet call like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="styles.css" type="text/css"?>
```

into the resulting XML so that after transformation I get a new XML doc that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="styles.css" type="text/css"?> <!--THIS LINE INJECTED-->
<CATALOG>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Is there a way to do this within the XSLT transformation or will I need to do some further post-processing of the resulting XML to inject the  tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `xsl:processing-instruction` element, as outlined in [7.3 Creating Processing Instructions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt11/#N4760), thus:

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">
href="styles.css" type="text/css"
</xsl:processing-instruction>
```